# Tabs are Slow/Laggy

Tags: java, android

so i have 3 tabs and i have noticed that my tabs are slow. how can i improve the performance of the tabs. The tabs have list views.

what are the ways to improve performance for the tabs

i think the problem is because i have a list view with a database and it is constantly calling the onActivityCreated and the list is updating(i m not sure)

here is my code this fragment is causing the problem

```
public class Jornal extends Fragment {

DataBasaJurnal dbJ;
ListView listView;
public static myAdapter myA;
ImageButton AddButton;



@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    View view = inflater
            .inflate(R.layout.fragment_jornal, container, false);



    return view;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    AddButton = (ImageButton) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.buttonAddJornal);
    AddButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), AddToJornal.class));

        }
    });

    listView = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.listViewJurnal);
    dbJ = new DataBasaJurnal(getActivity());
    dbJ.open();

    new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            myA = new myAdapter(getActivity(), dbJ.getAllRowre());
            listView.setAdapter(myA);
        }
    });
    listView.setAdapter(myA);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            int mySuperInt = dbJ.countCases() - position;
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(getActivity(),
                    JornalListViewClick.class);
            myIntent.putExtra("intVariableName", mySuperInt);
            listView.setEnabled(false);


                startActivity(myIntent);


        }
    });

    }



@Override
public void onStart() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStart();

    onActivityCreated(null);

    System.out.println("ok");
    listView.setEnabled(true);



}

class myAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

public myAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
    super(context, c);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    View retView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_row_jornal, parent,
            false);

    return retView;
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

    TextView textViewMonth = (TextView) view
            .findViewById(R.id.textViewDateWeek);
    textViewMonth.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(cursor
            .getColumnName(1))));
    TextView textViewMonthDay = (TextView) view
            .findViewById(R.id.textViewDateNum);
    textViewMonthDay.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(cursor
            .getColumnName(2))));
    TextView textViewUserInput = (TextView) view
            .findViewById(R.id.textViewUserInput);
    textViewUserInput.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(cursor
            .getColumnName(5))));
    TextView textViewUserTitle = (TextView) view
            .findViewById(R.id.textViewTitelFromDB);
    textViewUserTitle.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(cursor
            .getColumnName(6))));
    TextView textViewLucid = (TextView) view
            .findViewById(R.id.textViewhasLucid);



}
```

}}

Comment: Use Traceview and determine exactly where your problem lies.

Comment: i have done some resources and i think the problem is because i have a list view with a database and it is constantly calling the onActivityCreated

Comment: On a side note, `onActivityCreated()` is an activity life cycle function and should **never** be called manually. Wrap your code in your own function and call it in places you want instead.

Comment: Oh i didn't think of that. didn't solve my problem but thanks anyway